# Calculate number of pages in docs file by dot net and C# and Syncfusion.DocIO.Net.Core Package

Tags: c#, syncfusion, .net-core-3.1

I have a .net Core 3.1 webapi.
I want to get the number of pages are in docs and doc file.
Am using the  `Syncfusion.DocIO.Net.Core`  package to perform operation on docs/doc file. But it does't provide feature to update stat of file and display only the PageCount: `document.BuiltinDocumentProperties.PageCount;`
This is not updated by files. Would you someone suggest me how i can calculate arithmetically.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the page count from BuiltInProperties of the document using DocIO as below. It shows the page count in the document while creating the document using Microsoft Word application and also it still returns the same page count if we manipulate the document using DoIO.

```
 int count = document.BuiltinDocumentProperties.PageCount;
```

If you want to get the page count, after manipulating the Word document using DocIO, we suggest you to convert the word document to PDF, and then you can retrieve the page count as like below.

```
 WordDocument wordDocument = new WordDocument(fileStream, FormatType.Docx);
 DocIORenderer render = new DocIORenderer();
 //Sets Chart rendering Options.
 render.Settings.ChartRenderingOptions.ImageFormat = ExportImageFormat.Jpeg;
 //Converts Word document into PDF document
 PdfDocument pdfDocument = render.ConvertToPDF(wordDocument);
 int pageCount = pdfDocument.PageCount;
```

Since Word document is a flow document in which contents will not be preserved page by page; instead the contents will be preserved sequentially section by section. Each section may extend to various pages based on its contents like table, text, images etc.

Whereas Essential DocIO is a non-UI component that provides a full-fledged document object model to manipulate the Word document contents. Hence it is not feasible to get the page count directly from Word document using DocIO.

We have prepared the sample application to get the page counts from the word document and it can be downloaded from the below link.
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/GetPageCount16494613